# Component coordinates

Tags: java, swing, point, mouse-listeners, swingutilities

I'm trying to **get components coordinate's in relation to its parent**. For example, when I have a *JFrame* of size *500x500*, which has a child - *JPanel* - at *[50, 10]* I should get *[50, 10]* as a result. However easy may it seem, I'm keep getting wrong coords (*[0, 0]* or *[3, 24]*).

Here's my JPanel's code:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener { 
    private Component parent;   
    private String strName;

    public MyPanel(Component pr, String name, int w, int h) {
        super();

        parent = pr;
        strName = new String(name);

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(w, h);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /* MouseListener implementation */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            int x = event.getX(); int y = event.getY();
            Point pnt = new Point(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(0, 0), parent));
            System.out.println(strName + ":" + pnt);    
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) { }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) { }
}
```

Any ideas?

[Java binary & source code (*.tar.xz)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90959340/java-mouse-listener.tar.xz)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Point pnt = new Point(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, event.getPoint(), parent));
```

isnatead of using (Which is never used BTW atleast in provided snippet):

```
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
```

and you shouldnt do this:

```
Point pnt = new Point(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(0,0), parent));
```

or else the co-ordinates returned will always be in respect of (0,0).

You could also do (which I think you were going to but forgot x and y :P):

```
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
    Point pnt = new Point(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this,
                                               new Point(x,y), parent));
```

EDIT:

If i understand what you want then why bother with all that code? In each `JPanel`s `MouseListener`'s `mouseClicked()` do this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println(this.getX()+" "+this.getY());//print x and why co-ords for MyJpanel
}
```

Comment: it returns clickEvent coordinates, I would like to get JPanel coordinates info

Comment: @Robin92 why do you want it to keep returning the panels co-ordinates? which will be 50 10 unless altered?

Comment: It's just a "fun-app" before doing actual application. I'll need those coordinates to do a valid drawing :)

Comment: @Robin92 so to clarify you want the co-ordinates relative to its parent? as in if I click the bottom right corner of the frame which should give 500,500 you want 450,490? or you still want (50,10)

Comment: Frankly speaking I would like to get the upper-left point (in relation to *JFrame*) of my *JPanel* (rectangle). So in the source code provided it would be *(0,0)* for *"panel1"* and *(100, 0)* for *"panel2"* :)

Comment: I've just understood how stupid I am... Drawing takes coordinates where *(0,0)* is a component's origin... Sorry for this pointless thread and thanks for help ;/